# PowerShell: Start-Process never exits when child process is running

Tags: powershell

I use Start-Process to start process which also starts process:

```
$p = Start-Process "ProcessRunner.exe" -ArgumentList "notepad.exe"  -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
$exitCode = $p.ExitCode
```

**ProcessRunner** (parent process) starts application specified in **ArgumentList** ('notepad.exe' - child process) then exits with some specific exitCode that is use in another part of the script.

In powershell 2.0 this worked as I expected: script continued immediatelly after ProcessRunner exited even if child process continues execution.

In powershell 4.0 script execution is suspended until notepad.exe exits as well.

Is it possibble to get (in ps4) exitCode of the parent process when child process is still running (i.e. behavior of ps2)?

EDIT:
simple ProcessRunner that can be used to reproduce the issue:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    int result;

    try
    {
        Process prc = new Process();
        prc.StartInfo.FileName = args[0];
        result = prc.Start() ? 0 : 1;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        result = -1;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("ExitCode = {0}", result);
    return result;
}
```

using `$p.WaitForExit()` instead of `-Wait` brings better results (scripts continues execution - as requested) but `$p.ExitCode` is not set and its value is `$null` as you can make sure yourself by `Write-Host "[PS] ExitCode = $p.ExitCode"` (printed result is `[PS] ExitCode =`)

Comment: Try removing `-Wait`?  Furthermore, to be able to fit a [mcve], I feel like we would need to understand `ProcessRunner` at least some, but I'm not sure if this is a legit utility, or one you built on your own?

Comment: see edited question (ProcessRunner example added, -Wait helps partially)

Comment: I would say that the behavior in PoSH 2.0 is flawed :)

Comment: Why are you using Start-Process to start a process that starts a process? Can't you just skip `ProcessRunner`?